# Google App Engine endpoints - generate android library - method category() is already defined in class

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I was trying generate a android client library for my GAE Endpoints projects and I got an odd issue. When I generate a iOS client library, everything is fine, but for Android GAE it generates a mess of java files with errors (I tested on JDK 1.7, 1.8).
I tried using appcfg.sh and maven with different versions of the GAE SDK but the result is the same.

This is a sample log:

```
symbol:   class Ranking
location: class MyApp
myApp-backend/myApp-backend-api-war/myApp/src/main/java/com/appspot/myAppserver/myApp/MyApp.java:1482: error: cannot find symbol
public Rating rating() {

symbol:   class Rating
location: class MyApp
myApp-backend/myApp-backend-api-   war/myApp/src/main/java/com/appspot/myAppserver/myApp/MyApp.java:1757:     error: cannot find symbol
public User user() {

symbol:   class User
location: class MyApp
myApp-backend-api-    war/myApp/src/main/java/com/appspot/myAppserver/myApp/MyApp.java:2321:     error: method category() is already defined in class MyApp
public Category category() throws java.io.IOException {
```

Could it be caused by any error in the project structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what Google Cloud Support had to say about this in response to our case number 05478936:

**Google Cloud Support Response on 2/26/2015 1:57 PM:**

At that point, I was able to observe the compilation errors you described in your initial ticket description when running mvn appengine:endpoints_get_client_lib. I believe the cause of these compilation errors relates to how youve structured/written your code, specifically with reference to Guices injection feature. Ill do my best to give insight on how these compilation errors can be solved, but note that they dont appear to be caused by the SDK, but rather by your use of Guice, and so the next step is to seek support from the channels the Guice project[1] has defined for support, such as the github issues page[2] or the mailing lists[3][4]. You can read in depth about the injection feature specifically in their wiki[5], in addition to leveraging your own current knowledge of how Guice works, and the use youre making of its features in coding your app.

The various errors, broken down by their kind, are listed below, along with the apparent cause. All these errors take place in target/endpoints-client-libs/uluvit/src/main/java/com/appspot/uluvitserver/uluvit/Uluvit.java, which seems to be a generated file put together by Guice, following your injection patterns, ultimately deriving from the directions given in com.uluvit.backend.application.UluvitServletModule.java. Line numbers will reference where the compilation errors occur in this resulting file Uluvit.java.

Error form: method _____ is already defined in class Uluvit(..*)? ...:

This can be observed twice in the compiler errors, relative to lines 2979, 2389. We can see on 2979 that the method category() is defined, returning an object of class Category, while the same method signature was already used on line 130.

Error form: class _____ is already defined in class Uluvit(..*)? ...:

This can be observed four times in the compiler errors, relative to lines 947, 2396, 2882, 2985. We can see on line 947 that the class Discussion is defined, while the same class has already been defined on line 810, but with a different inheritance.

constructor _____ in class _____ cannot be applied to given types:

This can be observed twice in the compiler errors, relative to lines 941, 2876. We can see on line 941 that the code return new Discussion(); is attempted, while on line 827, where the constructor is defined for Discussion, we see it takes two java.lang.Long arguments, rather than no arguments.

cannot find symbol:

This error occurs three times in the maven compile-phase error output, for the classes Ranking, Rating, and User. On lines 1293, 1482, and 1757 respectively, there is a method attempting to return each of these classes, which are defined just below. It may be that the

no suitable method found for initalize (Uluvit.Category)

This error occurs once in the maven compile-phase error output. On line 2980, the following code occurs:

Category result = new Category();
initialize(result);
return result;

The issue is, the function Uluvit.initialize() is used, which comes from line 115, and has a different method signature:

protected void initialize(com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest httpClientRequest) throws java.io.IOException

This concludes the analysis of the compiler errors your project generates.

I hope my investigation has been helpful to you. It seems the error isnt with the SDK, but rather with your use of Guice to generate your Api class. Im not qualified to speak in depth on Guice or how to debug your injections, but Im glad I was able to help determine this much at any rate. Perhaps you have multiple classes that dont overlap in other files being brought together in ways that their names conflict, due to the injection pattern producing the monolithic service class Uluvit.

Being that weve identified the issue isnt with the SDK, but rather with Guice, for which you can access support through the github pages issue feature or by posting to the mailing list, in addition to stackoverflow on the guice tag, would you like me to go ahead and close this case now? Just let me know if you have any additional questions about the SDK and Ill be happy to help.

Best wishes,

Nick
Technical Solutions Representative
Cloud Platform Support

[1] https://github.com/google/guice
[2] https://github.com/google/guice/issues
[3] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-guice
[4] https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-guice-dev
[5] https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections

**Google Cloud Support Response on 2/26/2015 3:05 PM:**

I don't think the issue is the version of Guice as much as the use pattern, at this point. The naming conflicts are seeming to derive from the numerous @Inject annotations in the various classes that come together to create Uluvit.java. You'll need to debug your Guice injections according to what you know about how they work. Getting in contact with people from Guice is a good step in this direction.

Now, as far as a recommended DI library, we don't recommend any particular library, as we want to remain open as to what kind of choices developers make. The definition of the best tool is the one that most closely matches your needs, however you interpret them.

I believe that given the analysis from my previous message, and getting in touch with the Guice people, along with reviewing your injections and naming of classes, methods, you should be able to debug these compile errors. The reason the generate client libraries operation is failing is due to these compile errors in Uluvit.java, not due to any issue with the endpoints tools or SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Below is what Google Cloud Support had to say about this in response to our case number 05478936.  Where they refer to our issue posted on the Guice issue tracker, they're referring to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-guice/ou-ZUhCwJko:

**Google Cloud Support Response on 3/2/2015 9:09 AM:**

I've read through the thread you posted in the Guice issue tracker, and I've also been doing some in-depth reading on Guice because I want to make sure that you get the best solution possible here, and that I can understand exactly what's happening in your app. After reading your source code in depth, I can see that the Guice injections are not quite the issue - I had taken Guice's injection system as the cause of the naming conflicts of the Uluvit.java file.

Upon closer inspection of your API method hierarchies, I can see that it's rather the naming of API methods that is causing the behaviour. I'll explain, so you know exactly what's happening, and I'll also list the couple minor changes you'll need to make to get a successful compilation. In addition, I've submitted a docs improvement request to warn about this potential name conflict and also started the process to implement more useful error messages during endpoint client library generation, in cases like yours.

So, this is what’s happening:

- The endpoints client library generation code for Java creates source files by reading through your code to find the Api-annotated classes and methods.
- It then attempts to compile those classes and create a .jar you can load in as a dependency to your client. In the case of your app, all the multiple *Endpoint.java classes are brought together to build the one file Uluvit.java which will be compiled.
- When you have an API method "user.friends", it creates a User class inside the generated Uluvit API service class to group all the "user.*" methods, and a Friends class inside of User to handle that method request.
- The User.Friends class has been created because it corresponds to an API method (being the last symbol in the hierarchy, it's a method, while the others are just to help provide naming context). For each method in your API, it will be grouped in subclasses like this, representing the method hierarchy, until it reaches the actual method, which will be a class extending UluvitRequest, which extends AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest, representing a request handler on your API for that method, returning an object of type T.
- If you also use "friends" as part of a method hierarchy in addition to having been a method already, the naming conflict will result, since "user.friends.acceptRequest" (and other such methods) will need to create another Friends class (previously a method, not a class grouping methods inside of it) inside the User class to group all the "user.friends*" methods.

In this case, changing "user.friends" to "user.friends.list", in line with its actual function, eliminates the name-conflicts and furthermore keeps your "user.friends" methods all at a uniform level of the hierarchy. The same issue occurred for several methods, and this was all that needed to be changed:

1. in ItemEndpoint.java: change "category.item" to "category.item.list"
2. in ItemEndpoint.java: change "category" to "category.list"
3. in ItemEndpoint.java: change "user.item" to "user.item.list"
   4 in UserEndpoint.java: change "user.friends" to "user.friends.list"

Could you attempt to make these 4 changes and let me know whether client library generation goes well for you? In addition, if you have any further questions or issues at all, feel free to let me know and I'll be more than happy to help. I hope despite my initial confidence that we'd found the cause of the errors, that you feel supported in my commitment to making sure you get a solution once we figured out Guice injections were not the cause.

Sincerely,

Nick

Technical Solutions Representative

Google Cloud Platform